# Pandas - Creating Difference Matrix from Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a matrix to show the differences between the rows in a Pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Country':['GB','JP','US'],'Values':[20.2,-10.5,5.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like this:

```
  Country  Values
0      GB    20.2
1      JP   -10.5
2      US     5.7
```

To become something like this (differences going vertically):

```
  Country     GB     JP     US
0      GB    0.0  -30.7   14.5
1      JP   30.7    0.0   16.2
2      US   14.5  -16.2    0.0
```

Is this achievable with built-in function or would I need to build a loop to get the desired output? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a standard use case for numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
df['Values'].values - df['Values'].values[:, None]
Out: 
array([[  0. , -30.7, -14.5],
       [ 30.7,   0. ,  16.2],
       [ 14.5, -16.2,   0. ]])
```

We access the underlying numpy array with the values attribute and `[:, None]` introduces a new axis so the result is two dimensional.

You can concat this with your original Series:

```
arr = df['Values'].values - df['Values'].values[:, None]
pd.concat((df['Country'], pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df['Country'])), axis=1)
Out: 
  Country    GB    JP    US
0      GB   0.0 -30.7 -14.5
1      JP  30.7   0.0  16.2
2      US  14.5 -16.2   0.0
```

The array can also be generated with the following, thanks to @Divakar:

```
arr = np.subtract.outer(*[df.Values]*2).T
```

Here we are calling [`.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) on the `subtract` ufunc and it applies it to all pair of its inputs.

Comment: Just for variety or funsake : `np.subtract.outer(*[df.Values]*2)`.

Comment: Hmm seems like the order won't render same output as desired. So, negating it would be one way as noted by jezrael.

Comment: So, just transpose it afterwards : `np.subtract.outer(*[df.Values]*2).T` to avoid having the same answer :)

Comment: @Divakar - transpose here is same as negating?

Comment: @Divakar I put a minus sign after your comment. That would also work right?

Comment: Transpose works because its pairwise subtractions. Minus would work too. But transpose might be .. even better (not tested), as its just a view.

Comment: Needed something similar, and trying the Numpy for kicks, but get `NotImplementedError`: `if method == "outer":`  ...  `# GH#27198`; Looks like something broke.

Answer (score 3):

I try improve [`Divakar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266633/pandas-creating-difference-matrix-from-data-frame#comment79495965_46266707) comment:

```
a = np.column_stack([df['Country'], np.subtract.outer(*[-df.Values]*2)])

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Country'] + df['Country'].tolist())
print (df)
  Country    GB    JP    US
0      GB     0 -30.7 -14.5
1      JP  30.7     0  16.2
2      US  14.5 -16.2     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
DF=pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.Country, df.Country)), columns=['l1', 'l2'])
df=df.set_index('Country')
DF['v1']=DF.l1.map(df['Values'])
DF['v2']=DF.l2.map(df['Values'])
DF['DIFF']=DF['v2']-DF['v1']
DF.pivot(index='l1', columns='l2', values='DIFF').fillna(0).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None,1)
Out[94]: 
      GB    JP    US
GB   0.0 -30.7 -14.5
JP  30.7   0.0  16.2
US  14.5 -16.2   0.0
```

---

Option 2
using `apply`

```
A=df['Values'].apply(lambda x : df['Values']-x)
A.columns=df.Country
A['Country']=df.Country


A
Out[124]: 
Country    GB    JP    US Country
0         0.0 -30.7 -14.5      GB
1        30.7   0.0  16.2      JP
2        14.5 -16.2   0.0      US
```