# Compare rows with conditions and generate a new dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big dataframe with this structure:

```
Timestamp    Val1
```

Here you can see a real sample:

```
    Timestamp           Temp         
0   1622471518.92911    36.443       
1   1622471525.034114   36.445       
2   1622471531.148139   37.447      
3   1622471537.284337   36.449      
4   1622471543.622588   43.345      
5   1622471549.734765   36.451      
6   1622471556.2518     36.454      
7   1622471562.361368   41.461     
8   1622471568.472718   42.468   
9   1622471574.826475   36.470
```

What I want to do is compare the `Temp` column with itself and if is higher than "X", for example 4, and the time between they is lower than "Y", for example 180 min, then I save some data of they.

Now I'm using two `for` loops one inside the other, but this expends to much time and usually `pandas` has an option to avoid this.

This is my code:

```
cap_time, maxim = 180, 4
cap_time = cap_time * 60
temps= df['Temperature'].values
times = df['Timestamp'].values

results = []
for i in range(len(temps)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(temps)):
        print(i,j,len(temps))
        if float(temps[j]) > float(temps[i])*maxim:
            timeIn = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(times[i]))
            timeOut = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(times[j]))
            diff = timeOut - timeIn
            tdiff = diff.total_seconds()
            
            if dd > cap_time:
                break
            else:
                res = [temps[i], temps[j], times[i], times[j], tdiff/60, cap_time/60, maxim]
                results.append(res)
                break

# Then I save it in a dataframe and another actions
```

Can `Pandas` help me to achieve my goal and reduce the execution time? I found `dataFrame.diff()` but I'm not sure is what I want (or I don`t know how to use it).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post a sample of your original dataframe. `print(df.head(10))` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of avoiding the nested `for` loops, you can already speed things up by avoiding all unnecessary calculations and conversions within the loops. In particular, you can use NumPy [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266707/13014172) to define a Boolean array beforehand, in which you can look up whether the condition is met:

```py
import numpy as np

temps_diff = temps - temps[:, None]
times_diff = times - times[:, None]

condition = np.logical_and(temps_diff > maxim, 
                           times_diff < cap_time)

results = []
for i in range(len(temps)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(temps)):
        if condition[i, j]:
            results.append([temps[i], temps[j], 
                            times[i], times[j], 
                            times_diff[i, j]])
            
results
```

```
[[36.443, 43.345, 1622471518.92911, 1622471543.622588, 24.693477869033813],
...
 [36.454, 42.468, 1622471556.2518, 1622471568.472718, 12.22091794013977]]
```

To avoid the loops altogether, you could define a 3-dimensional full results array and then use the `condition` array as a Boolean mask to filter out the results you want:

```py
import numpy as np

n = len(temps)

temps_diff = temps - temps[:, None]
times_diff = times - times[:, None]

condition = np.logical_and(temps_diff > maxim, 
                           times_diff < cap_time)
            
results_full = np.stack([np.repeat(temps[:, None], n, axis=1), 
                         np.tile(temps, (n, 1)), 
                         np.repeat(times[:, None], n, axis=1), 
                         np.tile(times, (n, 1)), 
                         times_diff])

results = results_full[np.stack(results_full.shape[0] * [condition])]
results.reshape((5, -1)).T
```

```
array([[ 3.64430000e+01,  4.33450000e+01,  1.62247152e+09,
         1.62247154e+09,  2.46934779e+01],
       ...
       [ 3.64540000e+01,  4.24680000e+01,  1.62247156e+09,
         1.62247157e+09,  1.22209179e+01],
       ... 
      ])
```

As you can see, the resulting numbers are the same as above, although this time the `results` array will contain more rows, because we didn't use the shortcut of starting the inner loop at `i+1`.

Comment: Looks great! But `times_diff = times - times[:, None]` is to much for my computer and crash it, `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.6 GiB for an array with shape (42778, 42778) and data type float64`...

Comment: Since you're only interested in pairwise comparisons where the time difference is less than `cap_time`, you could divide the data into batches, as long as you let them overlap by `cap_time`.

Comment: mmm I'm new in broadcasting, but I'm thinking, if I batch my data, I not lose combinations between batches? Looks very interesting this topic, but I'm not sure to know how to do it right now. Thank you very much! @Arne

Comment: Assuming the data are sorted by time, say the last row in batch 1 has time `t_1`, then if you let batch 2 start at time `t_1 - cap_time`, and so on, then you won't lose any relevant combinations between batches.