# Calculate time difference as decimal in a difference matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analyzing timecard data and comparing employee's clockin/out times to each other. I'm exploring the data using [a difference matrix in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266707/343215). How do I convert the day, hour timedelta to decimal, or even just a sensible +/- without the `-1 days +23:40:00` weirdness?

```
employees = [('GILL', datetime(2022,12,1,6,40,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,30,0)),
             ('BOB', datetime(2022,12,1,6,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,14,10,0)),
            ('TOBY', datetime(2022,12,1,14,0,0), datetime(2022,12,1,22,30,0))]
labels = ['name', 'clockin', 'clockout']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(employees, columns=labels)
```

and my difference matrix is constructed with these two lines:

```
arr = (df['clockin'].values - df['clockin'].values[:, None])
pd.concat((df['name'], pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df['name'])), axis=1)
```

|  | name | GILL | BOB | TOBY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GILL | 0 days 00:00:00 | -1 days +23:20:00 | 0 days 07:20:00 |
| 1 | BOB | 0 days 00:40:00 | 0 days 00:00:00 | 0 days 08:00:00 |
| 2 | TOBY | -1 days +16:40:00 | -1 days +16:00:00 | 0 days 00:00:00 |

The trick to get a decimal difference is to use Pandas Datetime assessor's `total_seconds()` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html). But, this has no place in the `arr` array expression.

---

Here is `total_seconds()` doing it's magic:

```
df['workhours'] = round((df['clockout'] - df['clockin']).dt.total_seconds() / 60.0 / 60.0, 2)
```

I tried an apply on the time columns, but I can't get it to work. This might be the easy answer.

```
df_in.apply(lambda x: (x.total_seconds() / 60.0 / 60.0), columns=['BOB', 'GILL', 'TOBY'])
```

Comment: i cant reproduct your example. becuz df2 doesnt exist

Comment: @PandaKim I fixed it. The example uses only one DataFrame. DF2 was from my Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

Your following expression computes the numpy timedelta:

```py
type((df['clockin'].values - df['clockin'].values[:, None])[0][0])

[Out]:
numpy.timedelta64
```

Just divide it by `np.timedelta64(1, 'h')` or `np.timedelta64(1, 'm')`.

**Time difference in hours**

Divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 'h')`:

```py
arr = (df['clockin'].values - df['clockin'].values[:, None]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
pd.concat((df['name'], pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df['name'])), axis=1)

[Out]:
   name      GILL       BOB      TOBY
0  GILL  0.000000 -0.666667  7.333333
1   BOB  0.666667  0.000000  8.000000
2  TOBY -7.333333 -8.000000  0.000000
```

**Time difference in minutes**

Divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 'm')`:

```py
arr = (df['clockin'].values - df['clockin'].values[:, None]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
pd.concat((df['name'], pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df['name'])), axis=1)

[Out]:
   name   GILL    BOB   TOBY
0  GILL    0.0  -40.0  440.0
1   BOB   40.0    0.0  480.0
2  TOBY -440.0 -480.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

we need reproducible and minimal example for answer. lets make

```
data = [['GILL', pd.Timedelta('0 days'), pd.Timedelta('-1 days +23:20:00')], 
        ['BoB', pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:40:00'), pd.Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'GILL', 'BOB'])
```

`df`

```
    name    GILL                BOB
0   GILL    0 days 00:00:00     -1 days +23:20:00
1   BoB     0 days 00:40:00     0 days 00:00:00
```

**Code**

```
df[['GILL', 'BOB']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds())
```

`result`

```
    GILL    BOB
0   0.0 -2400.0
1   2400.0  0.0
```

make result to columns

```
df[['GILL', 'BOB']] = df[['GILL', 'BOB']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds())
```

`df`

```
    name    GILL        BOB
0   GILL    0.0         -2400.0
1   BoB     2400.0      0.0
```